# How to shift the data in a list

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq, list, arraylist

I have the following case and I want to get a general solution without heavy looping and slicing .

Firstly :

I initialize `N` which through it I calculate the list size (initial size) :

Through this Equation `N(N-1)/2`..

let's say I set `N = 5` so  the initial size will be `10` .

After that I fill the list with one's and zeroes with some method .

Like this :

> 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1

This list segmented according to N where the segments are (N-1).

So

- The First Segment is : `0 1 0 1`
- The Second Segment is : `1 1 0`
- The Third Segment is : `1 0`
- and The Forth Segment is : `1`

> [0 1 0 1] [1 1 0] [1 0] [1]

What I wanna to do is if I enter any number as input N again:

Maintain the previous data with the proper shifting

According to the new size .for example if N=6 so  the size will be 15

So I will have 5 segments in stead of 4

I want it like this :

> [0 1 0 1 **0**] [1 1 0 **0**] [1 0 **0**] [1 **0**] [**0**]

And vice verse If i enter N = 7 firstly and fill it .then i enter N = 4

I wanna to make the proper shifting

Answer (score 2):

It seems that `LinkedList` is the most appropriate collection class for you. It enables you to insert and remove elements in constant time from anywhere in the list.

Given below are algorithms for increasing and decresing N by one. Both operations are O(N).

```
// the whole list of integers
var data = new LinkedList<int>();

// stores the final node of each segment
var segmentEnds = new LinkedList<LinkedListNode<int>>();

/* INCREASING */
// increase all existing segments by one
var node = segmentEnds.First;
while (node != null)
{
    node.Value = data.AddAfter(node.Value, 0);
    node = node.Next;
}

// add the last segment of size 1
segmentEnds.AddLast(data.AddLast(0));

/* DECREASING */
if (data.Count > 0)
{
    // remove the last element from each segment
    node = segmentEnds.First;
    while (node != null)
    {
        var temp = node.Value.Previous;
        data.Remove(node.Value);
        node.Value = temp;
        node = node.Next;
    }

    // remove the last (now empty) segment
    segmentEnds.RemoveLast();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Any reason that you have to have these in a single list? It seems that what you have is a list of n lists here so creating one list of size N whcih holds lists of size 1 to N inside. This way when if you increase N you just add the appropriate number of 0s to each list and create your new lists with just 0 in. If you decrease N I'm not sure what the rule is but I suspect by comparison you will just remove the appropciate number of short lists and then remove the last however many elements from the other lists.

It doesn't work in terms of having a single arraylist but it is a better way to store the data you described, I'd say. You can always get from the model I've described to the flattened list pretty easily anyway...

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should start to think in two dimensions and use a `List<Segment>` whereas a `Segment` is a `List<bool>`. By using this you should be able to easily add/remove a segment or to change all segments the way you like. But this would lead to *heavy looping* in some way, but i don't think you can't solve this without looping on any level.

Comment: there's no dimensions the brackets are only for clarifying how i wanna to handle the data in segments

Comment: @just_name: But what holds you back to organize that data in two dimensions? To the outer world your class can provide a one dimensional access (through IEnumerable or index operator), but the internal implementation can be 2-d.

Answer (score 1):

```
int N = 5;
var array = Enumerable.Range(1, N - 1).Select(i => Fill(i))
                      .SelectMany(x => x)
                      .ToArray();

int[] Fill(int len)
{
    int[] arr = new int[len];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) arr[i] = 1; //Fill
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: He's got only one list; the square brackets are notional - there is no "second dimension" to his structure.

Comment: yeah the square brackets are only for clarifying the segments

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Easy to flatten `listOfArrays.SelectMany(x => x).ToArray();`

Comment: How will this help him increase the size of the list by adding new segments?

Comment: Say I has the intial list :

 `List<int> li = new List<int>(10);
                li.Add(0);
                li.Add(1);
                li.Add(0);
                li.Add(1);
                li.Add(1);
                li.Add(1);
                li.Add(0);
                li.Add(1);
                li.Add(0);
                li.Add(1);`

Comment: How can  this help me if the size changed to `15` instead of `10` according to the equation ??

Comment: @just_name your formula `N(N-1)/2` is equal to `1+2+ ... +(N-1)` and above code will always result in array with correct length.

Comment: Okay , i have the previous list how then i could use your code to provide `0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0` if  the n =6

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, you are modeling a 2D data structure with a one-dimension list. Although it is somewhat unorthodox, it is commonly done to save on memory.

The easiest solution is to make copies on extending or contracting your list. When you need to shorten or to extend your list, create a new list of the target size, and then use two nested loops to do the copying, as if the original list were a 2D data structure. Making a mapping function that takes a `row`, a `column`, and an `N`, and returns an index into a plain list that corresponds to the `{row, column}` pair may be very helpful:

```
private static int MakeIndex(int r, int c, int N) {
    return (N*(N+1)-(N-r)*(N+1-r))/2+c;
}
```

Now you can translate an index of a pair `{r, c}` in the list of size `N1` to the index of the same pair in a list of size `N2`.

You can improve upon this solution by expanding and shrinking in place. The key issue is the direction in which you go: when shrinking, go front-to-back; when expanding, go back-to-front.

Comment: Could u give me a sample general code to achieve this please ?

Comment: Copying data around is not going to be a feasible solution when N is large (for N=5000, the minimum memory of storing N(N-1) integers is 100Mb).

Comment: @Knaģis Why wouldn't it be feasible? A minimally equipped PC these days comes with orders of magnitude more memory.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - image if you need to increase the segment size from 5000 to 6000 step by step. if those are integers, this approach would copy around about 120 Gb of data in the memory. You would not run out of memory but the performance would be terrible.

Comment: @Knaģis Why would it be more "terrible" than any alternative? 120GB of data is 120GB of data, there's no way around it if you want your data structure to remain flat. If you are willing to go with non-flat data structure, such as one in your answer, you are doubling (on 64-bit systems, tripling) the memory requirements right away, because for each 32-bit integer you store a 32-bit (or a 64-bit) pointer.

Comment: @Knaģis Unless I'm terribly wrong, your solution requires as many pointers as there are data items, because `LinkedListNode<T>` contains a pointer to `Next`, and you have a size-`N` linked list of linked list nodes, each of average size `N/2`. There are `N(N-1)/2` data items, therefore there are `N(N-1)/2` pointers.

Comment: Yes, there are many pointers used (it actually is way worse if the default LinkedList is used). In the end to determine the best algorithm we all need actual usage scenarios from the author.